# In terms of power consumption, which is better, more cores - less frequency, less cores - more frequency?

Tags: cpu, power-supply

When a CPU is powered on, even one of its cores, does it require more battery to increase the core's clock speed, or is more power required keeping that core at its current clock speed, and turning on a secondary core at the same clock speed?

My thinking is more cores at lower clock speed will use less power, am I wrong? If so, how?

Thanks all!

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how CPUs work. a given thread can run on only one Core, and a program that runs on only one thread cannot use a second core for anything. Only in the case were multiple threads are switching back and forth on a single core would a CPU ever face the situation you posed, where either a frequency increase or the use of a second core are possible solutions. With a singe thread all you can ever do is increase frequency. frequency and core count are solutions to different problems. freq lets you do one task fast, and multi-cores allow you to do many things at once.

Comment: CPUs are far more complicated then just core count and frequency.  Sure both have some impact, but so do many other factors.  Why are you asking this question?  **What practical bit of information are you trying to get out of it?**  I suspect it is so vague to be basically meaningless from a CPU design perspective.  I also suspect any vague answers to what you are asking would give you no useful information on what existing CPU you would choose for a given application.

Comment: I know how CPUs work. I am creating a kernel for my Android device, and am tweaking the governor. Was trying out different settings - More cores, less frequency, less cores more frequency. Its not so much as what CPU I should use, but how to control the CPU I already have in my phone. I selected an answer, because its very descriptive and detailed. Thanks all for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are designed to work pretty balanced, and take into account the max TDP in this case.

Example:

Core i7-920XM, Core i7-2920XM

```
#ac #ts Max freq    Calculation
4/3 2   2.26 GHz    2000 + (2 × 133) = 2000 + 267 = 2267
2   8   3.06 GHz    2000 + (8 × 133) = 2000 + 1067 = 3067
1   9   3.20 GHz    2000 + (9 × 133) = 2000 + 1200 = 3200

4/3 7   3.20 GHz    2500 + (7 × 100) = 2500 + 700 = 3200
2   9   3.40 GHz    2500 + (9 × 100) = 2500 + 900 = 3400
1   10  3.50 GHz    2500 + (10 × 100) = 2500 + 1000 = 3500
```

In the above, in the case of 3/4 active cores, the fq boost will only go as far as shown in the table to maintain TDP. In the case of 1 core, it will go way higher according the the default turbo boost steps.

But does one 3.2 GHz core beat 3 or 4 cores at 2.26GHz ?
Or does a 3.5Gz one beat 4x 3.2GHz ones ?
No, unless you use a single-core only app.

So there's your general answer: **cores win**.

If you want more details, you will have to do a pretty complex analysis to determine that with enough accuracy. But here's some help:

1. Check a whole CPU family like this [this one](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/91287/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-v4-Family#@Server) .
2. Find relevant CPUs. Take the ones with 8 , 12, 14, 16 cores from the same family (imperative to be same generation nm/version).
3. Put all that into an excel file and make 2 set of graphs: TDP and cores // TDP and frequency. Compare them.
4. Get test result or make your own tests at various cores / fqs.
5. You will then obtain something like [that](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-61820a6b86759c354d41dbbd16a0385b?convert_to_webp=true)

Note that you will have to consider how the turbo steps work in order to do relevant testing.

Comment: Beautiful answer! Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

The understanding I have, from a little reading I did somewhere, is that more speed involves using more power, and also involves generating more heat.  The computer industry kept making chips go faster as long as they could, but then, around the times that chips reached 3GHz of speed, they hit some limits.  So then superior chip performance has involved adding complexity to the chips, including making multiple components that can perform certain tasks, resulting in multiple cores.

More cores can generate less power.  This is especially true when some cores can run at reduced speed, including even being turned off entirely, to help reduce power.